# Is it possible to get a Canadian visa without concrete plans?

Tags: canada, indian-citizens

I am sent to US relatively frequently by my company for 2 week periods ,alone, but on a very short notice

I would like to use one such visit to visit Canada as well, but cannot make concrete plans since my US visit plans themselves are decided 3 days in advance at best. In such a situation, is it possible to even get a tourist visa for Canada? (flights from India to Canada are EXPENSIVE, Seattle to Canada should be way cheaper)

Comment: Seattle to Vancouver you could even take the bus, both Boltbus and Quick Shuttle provides service.

Comment: @chx Or the Cascades train

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not necessary to have specific travel plans, but it will be helpful to have a *general* idea of what and where you want to visit (for instance, "I want to spend a day visiting the Vancouver Aquarium and another day visiting the Vancouver Art Gallery").

Canada consular officers aren't looking for specific travel plans anyway, and most countries advise visa applicants to *not* finalize travel plans before a visa is approved anyway.

[What they *are* looking for](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-who.asp) is:

- Do your have strong ties to your home country?
- Will you depart Canada within the time allotted for your visit?
- Do you have enough money to support yourself while visiting?

As a frequent business visitor to the US, it should be very easy for you to prove these.

Comment: @Blackbird57 It looked like the right form to me. The thing is, in this person's case it's not _possible_ to have a detailed itinerary in advance. He could make one up, but a (possibly written) explanation of the situation combined with his large collection of passport admittance stamps from the US ought to be sufficient.

Comment: Funny how I know the names and requirements to other countries but not those where I live :) Anyway, the [average wait times](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/temp/visitors.asp#asia) exceeds his notice even in the best of cases